# SLComposeViewController. How to open device settings with adding Twitter or Facebook account

Tags: ios, slcomposeviewcontroller

```
if ([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter]) 
{
    // Device is able to send a Twitter message
}
```

How to handle option if device has not got Twitter or Facebook account to offer users open setting and add appropriate account? I mean that device will open setting page with Facebook/Twitter account settings automatically. Is this possible? Or I just need to show alert view and it is just one option to notify user about non logged in account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go ahead and display the `SLComposeViewController` for Twitter. The system will display an alert to the user for you with a settings button:

[image]

Comment: I was to about to re-build iOS in order to solve this issue, but then i found your solution, so simple and clean. +1